# how do i use an array i returned in my other method in java?

Tags: java, arrays, return

This is the array in the method that I'm returning:

```
public static int[] inputData()
{
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a file name: ");
String inputFile = kb.nextLine();
File file = new File(inputFile);
Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
if(!file.exists())
  {
  System.out.println("Error. File not found. Program will now exit.");
  System.exit(0);
  }
int j = read.nextInt();
int[] input = new int[j];
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
  {
  input[i] = read.nextInt();
  }
return input[i];
}
```

And this is my main method

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {

int[] input = new inputData();
printArray(input);
reverseArray(input);
sum(input);
mean(input);
min(input);
max(input);
evenOdd(input);
}
```

How do I use the array i returned in the main method?

Comment: What do you mean with "how can I use the array"? You wanna loop through it?

Comment: Use the array to **do** what?

Comment: I know I'm doing something wrong in the main method. So how would i properly use return the input[i] array in the main method so i could use it in my other methods?

Edit: because int[]  input = new inputData(); is giving me an error so I'm not sure what's the correct format

Comment: return input[i]; will just return an integer

Comment: I think `inputData` is a bad method name.  Methods should have a verb-like name.  Something like `getInputData` would be better.  See [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Well, now I see that "input" here code be interpreted as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

First: make `inputData` actually return the array:

```
return input;
```

Second: like this:

```
int[] input = inputData();
```

Answer (score 1):

This line in your code is wrong:

```
int[] input = new inputData();
```

This infers that inputData is a class. It should be:

```
int[] input = inputData();
```

And the inputData method should return the entire array, not just one element.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to fix in your code.

Make the method return the array:

```
return input;
```

And your `inputData` is a method, so you dont need to use `new`. Change it to this.

int[] input = inputData();